# How to use __iterationNum() custom function in JMeter to assign csv file to Http Request

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, csv-file, http

Here I'm  assigning  CSV file on the basis of loop count so that done by using `__iterationNum()` JMeter custom function (custom JMeter Function plugin added to JMeter) But this stuff is not working for me so I used this function like this:

`> D:\datas\latandlong\IndiaAddress\address${__iterationNum}.cs‌v`   FilePath name in CSV dataset config but not getting a result is there any other way to use this function I don't know about that.

So how to use this function if anybody having an idea please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use CSV Data Set Config this way so I would suggest considering using [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) functions instead.

[image: JMeter CSVRead StringFromFile]

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

---

You can also reach out to JMeter Developers via [JMeter Users Mailing List](http://jmeter.apache.org/mail.html) to clarify the expected behavior of the CSV Data Set Config, i.e. whether you can change CSV file path dynamically using JMeter functions or variables.